# Detect if user opens link in new tab and redirect to new url

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to do something that I'm not sure is possible or not?

The user opens the website. If they try to reopen the link in a new tab I need to redirect them to another page.

I've tried using `c#` to see if I can detect a page reload. This works, but if I put my code in the page load event for some reason it runs twice, and it redirects them no matter if it's the first time they opened or if they are opening in a new tab. I need to only happen if they open a new tab.

### My Code:

```
bool IsPageRefresh = false;
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  ViewState["ViewStateId"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  Session["SessionId"] = ViewState["ViewStateId"].ToString();
}
else
{
  if (ViewState["ViewStateId"].ToString() != Session["SessionID"].ToString()) ;
  {
    IsPageRefresh = true;
    if (IsPageRefresh == true)
    {
      Response.Redirect("~/Pages/EstimateList.aspx", true);
    }
  }
  Session["SessionId"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  ViewState["ViewStateId"] = Session["SessionId"].ToString();
}
```

Do I need to use `Javascript` or `jQuery` to do this? I'm really new to `Javascript` and `jQuery`.

Comment: While you may be able to hack something together to do this, all you are probably going to do is irritate the user by doing something they are not expecting.

Comment: I doubt you can do this. Certainly not server side and I'd imagine the JS will restrict this functionality in the browser as it's annoying and can be abused

Comment: I didn't get what you want. Does it matter if the user type again in the address bar or you just don't want to have 2 tabs of the same page to be open?

Comment: Ashkan, I just don't want to allow them to open it in a new tab.

Comment: You realise what a horrible user experience that is right?

Comment: @Liam If it can't be done it can't be done.  I just needed to check if it was possible.  Thank you.

Comment: @DavidG Yes I do.  Lol.  They want to do it this way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookies. When the user first open the page you send a cookie to the computer saying `PageOpened=true` , when the user opens it in the new tab check if there is a `cookie with PageOpened=true`, if there is, open your other link in the browser.

You can give your cookies a time limit or destroy them when the first site is closed or when the user opens the new tab etc..

I can't provide you the code as I never worked with c# on web but this should give you an idea on possible routes to the solution.

*P.S.: I would also find it irritating as a user but that is your call.*

Comment: Can it be done in Javascript?

Comment: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) and  [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) on cookies with javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
if(Request.Cookies["isPageRefresh"] == null)
{
   Response.Cookies["isPageRefresh"].Value = "true";
   Response.Cookies["isPageRefresh"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

}
if (!IsPostBack) 
{                  
 if (Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["isPageRefresh"].Value== "false") 
 { 
   Response.Redirect("~/Pages/EstimateList.aspx", true);
 } 
 //enter some code
}
  Response.Cookies["isPageRefresh"].Value = "false";
  //enter some code
```

because on each new tab click asp understand it as a new request. you should use cookies for checking isPageRefresh if false redirect or use global variable that doesn't have redirect effect like cache variable  value

Comment: Hi Syuash, IsPageRefresh = true; is inside of if (!IsPostBack).

Comment: Yes and use  bool IsPageRefresh = false; not in load_page method

Comment: Suyash, I don't understand?  Where do I need to put if if not in page load?

Comment: isPageRefresh=true;
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
              if (IsPageRefresh == true)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Pages/EstimateList.aspx", true);
                }
        }
        else
        {
           
                IsPageRefresh = false;
               
            }
because on each new tab click asp understand it as a new request if you should use cookies too for checking isPageRefresh             
        }

Comment: Why not just edit your answer? The above is basically unreadable